# WCF IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest modify request

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to modify request in WCF service.

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    string xmlRequest = request.ToString();

    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlRequest);

    //Some request modifications
    //Here i have XML what in want to send

    request = Message.CreateMessage(request.Version, request.Headers.Action, WhatHere?);
    request.Headers.Clear();            

    return null;
}
```

But i don't know what i can set in `CreateMessage` or maybe is different way to set my XML as request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass an [XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx) object representing the modified message. Below is an example taken from the article [How to inspect and modify WCF message via custom MessageInspector](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stcheng/archive/2009/02/21/wcf-how-to-inspect-and-modify-wcf-message-via-custom-messageinspector.aspx).

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
{
    Console.WriteLine("====SimpleMessageInspector+BeforeSendRequest is called=====");

    //modify the request send from client(only customize message body)
    request = TransformMessage2(request);

    return null;
}

//only read and modify the Message Body part
private Message TransformMessage2(Message oldMessage)
{
    Message newMessage = null;

    //load the old message into XML
    MessageBuffer msgbuf = oldMessage.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);

    Message tmpMessage = msgbuf.CreateMessage();
    XmlDictionaryReader xdr = tmpMessage.GetReaderAtBodyContents();

    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(xdr);
    xdr.Close();

    //transform the xmldocument
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("a", "urn:test:datacontracts");

    XmlNode node = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("//a:StringValue", nsmgr);
    if(node!= null) node.InnerText = "[Modified in SimpleMessageInspector]" + node.InnerText;

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
    xdoc.Save(xw);
    xw.Flush();
    xw.Close();

    ms.Position = 0;
    XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(ms);

    //create new message from modified XML document
    newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(oldMessage.Version, null,xr );
    newMessage.Headers.CopyHeadersFrom(oldMessage);
    newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(oldMessage.Properties);

    return newMessage;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible with this method to add something to the beginning to the envelope (before the open tag) and after the closing tag?
I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @maracuja-juice can you provide an example or ask a new question

Comment: I get <binary>somehasheddata</binary> instead of well formed one here:    xdoc.Load(xdr); Is this coded somehow?

Comment: Think link to the blog is dead. You can get it here: https://web.archive.org/web/20160314042452/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stcheng/archive/2009/02/21/wcf-how-to-inspect-and-modify-wcf-message-via-custom-messageinspector.aspx